# Weechat error: unknown command "script" (type /help for help)

Tags: command-line, python, scripts, irc

While trying to set an autoloading python script in Ubuntu, I received the error listed in the title.  A google search returned no similar issues and when I type

```
/help script
```

it returns:

```
No help available, "script" is not a command or an option.
```

I tried reinstalling weechat but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps below:

```
sudo apt-get purge weechat
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 11E9DE8848F2B65222AA75B8D1820DB22A11534E
sudo bash -c "echo 'deb https://weechat.org/ubuntu xenial main' >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/weechat.list"
sudo bash -c "echo 'deb-src https://weechat.org/ubuntu xenial main' >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/weechat.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install weechat-curses weechat-plugins
```

Start the client with `weechat` or `weechat-curses`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by recompiling weechat and upgrading from version 0.4.3 to 1.0.1.  It's working like a charm now.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove weechat
```

and from here follow the instructions in the readme that accompanies weechat from their website rather than the Ubuntu repo.